# Continuity. Need clarification of question

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In part **a** of a question, I proved that if a topological space $X$ is compact, and a topological space $Y$ is Hausdorff, then any continuous bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism.

The part **b** says this: *We have seen that the compactness of $X$ is necessary in order for the conclusion of **a** to be true. Show that the condition that $Y$ be Hausdorff  is necessary as well.*

Now, I have no worldly clue what the question is asking me to do. I suspect that the question is asking me to show that if $f: X  \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism where $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $X$ is Hausdorff as well. Which is something I can prove easily. But I don't think the language translates to this question. Can I get some help?

Full disclosure - this is an assignment question. And I'm not looking for any kind of a solution to any question that I have written. Just clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I think the question is asking you to produce an example of a continuous bijection $\;f:X\to Y\;$ ,with compact $\;X\;$ **but with** $\;Y\;$  non-Hausdorff that is not a homeomorphism...

Comment: Ah! Right, that makes sense

Comment: Think of some simple space with the trivial (or indiscrete) topology as image...

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe delete this hint. The OP is explicit he doesn't want hints.

Comment: The identity map $i: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ where the domain has the standard topology and the co-domain has the trivial topology should do the trick

Comment: @Math_QED That was a rather mild hint...and junkquill already wrote an answer.